# Refreshing demo website data for different timezone?

Tags: database, refresh, demo

I have a demo site which is open for public access to login, view, and try out our website.

The data is editable for public so I am refreshing the database of this demo site every midnight local time. Refreshing here means dropping the entire database and then re-importing a template database. The database I'm running is MySQL 5.7.

The problem is that there is a 3-5 minutes downtime when my script is refreshing the database.

This is not an issue for the clients on my timezone as it's midnight here but on the other side of the world, customers are complaining as they think that the demo site is down for some reason.

How do you approach this issue? I believe a lot of sites provide demo sites and they should refresh their data on a constant basis too (daily in my case).

Thank you!

Comment: By “refresh data” do you mean wiping out all users’ edits and restoring an original known set of data? I suggest editing your Question to explain in more detail exactly what work must be done. And mention what database.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I have edited my Question.

Comment: What exactly is your technique for recreating the database?

Comment: It's actually just a simple shell script which will drop, re-create, then re-import the db from the template db.